# How to make a php file at Magento root directory through plugin

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to make a php file at plugin root directory by code . Is there some way that plugin could make a php file at root directory . If yes then what is the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If using Magento 1**

Put the below code wherever you want to create a php file in root directory.

```
try{
      $_dir =  Mage::getBaseDir();  //i.e. /var/www/html/magento
      $_fileName = 'SAMPLE.php';
      $_content = "SAMPLE CONTENT FOR YOUR FILE";
    file_put_contents($_dir. DS . $_fileName, $_content);

}catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**Note:** Make sure you've given permission to the directory where you creating the file.

In case you want to create file in some other directory in Magento 1.x.

```
Mage::getBaseDir('app')  //i.e. /var/www/html/magento/app
Mage::getBaseDir('media') //i.e. /var/www/html/magento/media
Mage::getBaseDir('design') //i.e. Get design directory path
Mage::getBaseDir('code') //i.e. Gives code directory file path
Mage::getBaseDir('lib') //i.e. Gives lib directory file path
Mage::getBaseDir('skin') //i.e. Gives skin directory file path
Mage::getBaseDir('var') //i.e. Gives var directory file path
Mage::getBaseDir('cache') //i.e. Gives cache directory file path
Mage::getBaseDir('log') //i.e. Gives log directory file path
```

Comment: Thank you for your help . If i write  $base_path = Mage::getBaseDir();  it gave me the path of ROOT directory . After this if i write $base_path->writeFile("SAMPLE.php",$contents); It gave an error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function writeFile() on string  . Can you please help to fix it ?

Comment: As you using Magento 1, $base_path->writeFile("SAMPLE.php",$contents); is incorrect. Use the above code I mentioned for Magento 1.

Comment: Thank You ! Your code works for me . You saved my day !

Answer (score 0):

**If using Magento 2**

You can put this code in your plugin to create a file in `ROOT` directory.

```
try {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $filesystem = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
    $directoryList = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
    $rootDir = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite($directoryList::ROOT);

    $contents = "YOUR_CONTENT_GOES_HERE";
            $rootDir->writeFile("SAMPLE.php",$contents);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

You can also create file in other directories like media, var etc. Have a look at below file:

```
Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList
```

Comment: Thank you for your help . Dear i am working in Magento 1.9.4 . Can you please provide the code for magento 1.9 ?